# How to implement the delete method for BinarySearchTree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is my code. I am stuck on the delete part. The insert and get methods are all fine. I want to save the old tree so that I can link the node together soon.

```
private BinaryTree<K, V> left, right;
public BinaryTree(K key, V value) {
    // Leaf node constructor
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (this.key.equals(key)) {
        // Replacing the value at the current node
        V ret = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return ret;
    }
    int comp = this.key.compareTo(key);
    if (comp < 0) {
        // this.key < key
        // Put the key we are inserting to the right
        // of the current key
        if (right == null) {
            // We have to create a node to the right
            // (Leaf node)
            right = new BinaryTree<K, V>(key, value);
            return null; // Per interface
        }
        return right.put(key, value);
    } else {
        // We don't support keys where equals and compareTo
        // disagree with each other.
        assert(comp != 0);
        // At this point, we know that comp > 0
        // Therefore, this.key > key
        // Put the key we are inserting to the left of current
        if (left == null) {
            // We have to create a node to the left
            // (Leaf node)
            left = new BinaryTree<K, V>(key, value);
            return null; // Per interface
        }
        return left.put(key, value);
        // Exercise: You could write a tiny little private method
        // to implement this redundant code in one place.
    }
}

public V get(K key) {
    int comp = this.key.compareTo(key);
    if (comp < 0) {
        // this.key < key
        // Recurse to the right
        if (right == null) {
            // Not in the tree
            return null;
        }
        return right.get(key);
    } else if (comp > 0) {
        // this.key > key
        // Recurse to the left
        if (left == null) {
            // Not in the tree
            return null;
        }
        return left.get(key);           
    } else {
        assert(this.key.equals(key));
        return value;
    }
}

public boolean containsKey(K key) {
    // Note: Doesn't work with null values!
    return get(key) != null;
}

public BinaryTree<K, V> delete(K key) {
    BinaryTree<K,V> tmp,childL,childR,OldTree;
    int comp=this.key.compareTo(key);
    if(comp<0){
        //this.key<Key goes right
        if(this.right==null){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nothing you can delete here");

        }
        else{

            return this.right.delete(key);

                }

        }
    if(comp>0){
        if(this.left==null){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nothing you can delte here");
        }
        else{
            return this.left.delete(key);
        }
                }
    if(this.key.equals(key)){


    }
        {


        }
    //}
    // IMPLEMENT THIS FOR YOUR ASSIGNMENT!
    // Remove key from the tree, if it exists.
    // Throw UnsupportedOperationException if key isn't in the tree.
    // Return the new root node if we did delete the key.
    // (The new root node may be the same as the old one.)
    // If you deleted the last node in the tree, it will return null.
        return null;

}}
```

Some details are posted on the common, is it logical error on my code?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework...

Comment: I finished most of them,just stuck on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Delete is the most important step on binary trees, and IT IS your homework :) You must keep your tree valid, so when you find the node to be removed, you have three cases: leaf (and you remove it), one child only (replace the node with the child), two children (find the biggest node among the smallest - go to left one step then always right until you can do it - and copy it in place of the removed one, then apply deletion recursively on the node you have found, until you reach one of first two cases). Details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion
You can do it :)